# OwlCarousel2 jump to any other slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using OwlCarousel2 and have multiple slider at one page. my requirement is that when I click to "Next" or "Previous" icons i have to jump to slider for example form 2nd slider to 6th slider OR 6th slider to 4th slider.

I am using angular js one page structuring and my page url is like.
http://192.168.0.88:8000/consumer/#!/create/project/test/

My code snnipets:

HTML

```
   <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item" slidename="dog">
      <h4>1 dog</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" slidename="cat">
      <h4>2 cat</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" slidename="fish">
      <h4>3 fish</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" slidename="lion">
      <h4>4 lion</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    dots:false,
    autoplay:false,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    URLhashListener:false,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash',    
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      600:{
        items:1
      },
      1000:{
        items:1
      },
    }
  })
  // Listen to owl events:
  owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    location.hash = 'slide' + 2;
    location.hash = 'monkey';
  })
})
```

OwlCarousel2 in Angular

I am using a form that having multiple slides and each having different `input fields and radios` etc.

My requirement it that when clicking on `Next ot Prev` button I have to validate the current slide input fields if fields are blank or validation not math `don't slide` to next and stop at same slide and show the proper validations to user.

Slide 1:
[image]

Slide 2:

[image]

Slide 3:

[image]

If slide first is validated then move to second slide and so on. 
Any one please help me.

Please any one help how have full control on slide.

Comment: Do want code in angularjs or its mandatory in jquery

Comment: Thanks Anil,
will be better in angularjs

Comment: Check this http://embed.plnkr.co/pOIh2mOkj9N5HajbiC9h/

Comment: This is not use full for me